# Why are games lagging on my laptop?

Tags: pc, performance

I have a Dell laptop with these specifications:

> ```
> Intel B950 2.1 GHz
> 4 GB RAM
> Intel HD Graphics 2000
> Windows 8.1
> ```

I know these specs are low but it run games for others. I have seen people with same GFX card and playing games without any lag on **medium settings**. For example,

**Fifa 14** works on this guy's laptop without any lag. [**Youtube Link**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK1hZn8lctw) He says, it works on **60-70 FPS** without FRAPS. But on my laptop, it works on only **20-30 FPS** and lags continuously **(dropping to 4-10 FPS)**.

Sorry for tags, I couldn't create ones which fits for the question.

It happens to every game, even **COD:MW1**. *I have updated my drivers.*

Comment: Is it *lagging* or are you getting *FPS drops*?

Comment: Is it plugged in?

Comment: Make sure there is a reasonable graphic card on the laptop, the next time you purchase it. Your CPU is also very low spec for normal gaming.

Answer (score 5):

Intel integrated video cards are notorious for having sub-par gaming performance. You're going to be constantly struggling to get good frames with that setup, however there are a couple things you could try:

- **Uninstall any unwanted programs:** over time programs might accumulate. Some have processes running constantly in the background.
- **Disable any unwanted startup programs:** other programs you might want, but only use sparingly. you can disable startup programs so they only run when you need them.

A program I frequently use to flush the garbage out of my system is [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). It lets you manage installed programs, startup items, system cache, and registry cleanup. Since you're dealing with system files, take extra caution not to delete or remove anything you want to keep.

Comment: I would also recommend running a virus sweep.